# Python csv register_dialect delimiter is not working

Tags: python, csv, delimiter, writer, dialect

I have the written the code below to read in a large csv file with many variables and then just print 1 variable for every row in the outfile. It is working except that the delimiter is not being picked up.

```
import csv

fieldnames = ['tag']

outfile = open('ActiveTags.txt', 'w')
csv.register_dialect('me', delimiter=',', quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, lineterminator='')
writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, dialect='me')


with open('ActiveList_16.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
reader = csv.DictReader(f)

for row in reader:

    Tag = row['Tag']
    writer.writerow({'tag': Tag})


outfile.close()
```

What am I missing here? I do not understand why the delimiter is not working on the outfile.

Comment: but you're writing only 1 element. There's no delimiter in that case right?

Comment: Did you try Pandas.read_csv ? It's easier to use, the documentation is broad and if pandas dataframe don't suit you, you can just "toArray" it. 
Why make things difficult ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It's printing out 1 element per row in the in-file which is a few hundred. But it's not including a comma between each element.